# Lua SQL: peeking at cursors

Tags: lua, cursor, luasql

I am using LuaSQL, and query for a result set using `con:execute(sql_stmt)`, which returns a cursor.

How do I see if there is at least one row in that resultset, without doing a `cursor:fetch` to pop that first row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [doc](http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/manual.html#cursor_object) it appears you can use cur:numrows() if you are using MySQL, PostgreSQL, or Oracle:

> cur:numrows()
>       See also: cursor objects
>       Returns: the number of rows in the query result.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using an odbc driver to a MySQL database. numrows() didn't work for me.